# Type of Multiple Choice Questions I II III

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider the following:

An eight-by-eight chessboard.
An eight-by-eight chessboard with two opposite corners removed.
An eight-by-eight chessboard with all four corners removed.
Which of these can be tiled by two-by-one dominoes (with no overlaps or gaps, and every domino contained within the board)?

A. I only

B. II only

C. I and II only

D. I and III only

E. I, II, and III

Is there a specific name for these types of multiple choice questions, because I want to practice these?

Comment: Usually I ignore it but every now and then I get grumpy and can't help myself, but, I'm genuinely curious:  What thought process goes into titling a question as "Type of Multiple Choice Questions I II III"?   I mean do people think that the subject of a question changes by what labels the multiple choice options are labelled as?  Why not "Help with a math question containing 48 words"?

Comment: Hint:  What color are the opposite sides of a checkerboard?  What colors are the two squares covered by one domino?

Comment: "Is there a specific name for these types of multiple choice questions"  What type of questions?  Questions about chessboards.  Questions were the choices are roman numerals?  No.  There are no names for those types of questions at all.

Comment: questions where the choices are roman numerals @fleablood

Comment: Are you serious?  No, there is no word for questions where the multiple choice options are roman numerals and there is no way to study for them.  You might as well try to study for questions that contain 48 words.  Or are printed in books with yellow covers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about a name for these types of questions. But I do know how you should approach them.

Firstly, look at the easiest one to think about. Clearly it's impossible to tile a chess board with dominoes if two opposite corners are removed. This is because you end up with unequal numbers of black and white squares, but dominoes always cover an equal number of black and white squares. Now you can rule a line through anything with II:

1. I only
2. <del>II only</del>
3. <del>I and II only</del>
4. I and III only
5. <del>all of them.</del>

Now you have only option (1) and option (4) leftover. You know that I must be true, so it depends on whether or not III is true. (The answer is yes, by drawing a picture, so the answer is (4).)

To summarise, for this style of multichoice question, it is particularly effective to "get rid of what you know is false".